# How to add meta tags when using the play framework?

Tags: html, scala, playframework

I am using the play framework and have a main.scala.html file which currently holds all the header and footer information for each of my web pages. I then just reference the main.scala.html page for every other html page that I create. For example:

```
@main("enterprise") {

<!--=== Slider ===-->

<div class="layer_slider">
    <div id="layerslider-container-fw">        
        <div id="layerslider" style="width: 100%; height: 500px; margin: 0px auto; ">
```

As you can see the @main("enterprise") {} reference the main file while everything with the {} is the body portion of the enterprise page. I am however wanting to add meta tags to each of my pages individually and am wondering how should I do this? Would I have to enter a  tag to each of the html pages I wish to add meta to?

main.scala header:

```
@(activeMenu: String, headParts: Html = Html(""))(content: Html)
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 8]> <html lang="en" class="ie8"> <![endif]-->  
<!--[if IE 9]> <html lang="en" class="ie9"> <![endif]-->  
<!--[if !IE]><!--> <html lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->  
<head>
    <title>SpryPoint | Smart Solutions for Smart Utilities</title>


    <!-- Meta -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
```

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This topic is addressed in ***moreScripts and moreStyles equivalents*** section of [the template doc](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaTemplateUseCases) it can be for an instance:

```
@headParts = {
    <meta name="description" content="Some description for this page only...">
}

@main("enetrprise", headParts){
   Html content here ...
}
```

***Edit:*** So your `main.scala.html` would look (according to your additional comment) like:

```
@(activeMenu: String, headParts: Html = Html(""))(content: Html)
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>@activeMenu</title>
    @headParts
  </head>
  <body>
    <section class="content">@content</section>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I know I'm a little late, but what would I be putting in my main.scala.html file to account for this? Currently I have: @(activeMenu: String)(content: Html)

Comment: I've just added a bit more of my main.scala.html file to show you what it currently looks like. There is already a place for meta description however it applies itself to every page currently and I am trying to be specific to each.